# largest complete subtree in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm

I am defining a complete subtree as a tree with all levels full and the last level left justified i.e. all nodes are as far left as possible, and I want to find the largest subtree in a tree that is complete.

One method is to do the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20432173/3673043) for every node as root, which would take O(n^2) time.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: This feels like homework, so here's a hint: Suppose there is a complete tree of depth at least k rooted at vertex v.  Think about what properties the children of v must have: There must be zero or more children with at least k full levels below them, followed by at most 1 child with at least k-1 full levels and 1 partial level, followed by zero or more children with at least k-1 full levels.

Comment: Please indicate whether you mean binary or arbitrary trees.

Comment: Your definition of subtree differs from the actual definition of a subtree, which is "a tree consisting of a node in T and ALL of its descendants in T". Was this intended, because EPI seems to be referring to the actual definition?

Answer (score 4):

Since there isn't a C++ solution above, I have added my solution. Let me know if you feel there is anything incorrect or any improvements that can be made.

```
struct CompleteStatusWithHeight {
 bool isComplete;
 int height;
};

int FindLargestCompletetSubTreeSize(const unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>>& tree)
{
  return CheckComplete(tree).height;
}

CompleteStatusWithHeight CheckComplete(const unique_ptr<BinaryTreeNode<int>>& tree)
{
if (tree == nullptr) {
       return {true, -1};  // Base case.
}

auto left_result = CheckComplete(tree->left);
if (!left_result.isComplete) {
  return {false, 0};  // Left subtree is not balanced.
}
auto right_result = CheckComplete(tree->right);
if (!right_result.isComplete) {
  return {false, 0};  // Right subtree is not balanced.
}

bool is_balanced = abs(left_result.height - right_result.height) == 0;
bool is_left_aligned = (left_result.height - right_result.height) == 1;
bool is_leaf =  left_result.height  == -1 && right_result.height ==-1;
bool is_complete = is_balanced || is_left_aligned || is_leaf;

int height = max(left_result.height, right_result.height) + 1;
return {is_complete, height};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution in Python. It's working on the cases that I came up with.
The meaning of the return values are as follow:
[x,y,z]

- x = size of the largest complete subtree up to this node
- y = height of the subtree
- z: 0 - complete subtree, 1 - there is a node with a left child only in this subtree, 2 - not a complete subtree

  ```
  def largest_complete_tree(root):

      result = traverse_complete(root)
      print('largest complete subtree: {}'.format(result[0]))

  def traverse_complete(root):
      if root:
          left = traverse_complete(root.left)
          right = traverse_complete(root.right)
          max_complete = max(left[0], right[0])
          max_height = max(left[1], right[1])
          left_child_only = 1 if (left[2] == 1 and right[0] == 0) or (left[0] == 1 and right[0] == 0) else 0

          # 5 conditions need to pass before left and right can be joined by this node
          # to create a complete subtree.
          if left[0] < right[0]:
              return [max_complete, 0, 2]
          if left[2] == 2 or right[2] == 2:
              return [max_complete, 0, 2]
          if abs(left[1]-right[1]) > 1:
              return [max_complete, 0, 2]
          if (left[2] == 1 and right[2] == 1) or (left[2] == 0 and right[2] == 1):
              return [max_complete, 0, 2]
          if left[0] == right[0] and left[0] != 2**left[0] - 1:
              return [max_complete, 0, 2]
          return [left[0] + right[0] + 1, max_height + 1, left_child_only]
      else:
          return [0,0,0]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Define a rank of tree node, as the height of max complete subtree if this node is root. 
Define a width of node as number of nodes in last level of max complete subtree if this node is root.
So for each node in tree we have two number `(r, w)`. And `w <= 2^r`.

If node has zero or only one child, then node has `(r, w) = (1, 1)`.

If node has two children `(r1, w1)` and `(r2, w2)`, we have several cases:

1. `r1 > r2` when node will have `(r2 + 1, 2^r2 + w2)`
2. `r1 == r2` and `w1 == 2^r1` when node will have `(r1 + 1, w1 + w2)`
3. `r1 == r2` and `w1 < 2^r1` when node will have `(r1 + 1, w1)` Example:

```
         root     
         ....
    /  \     /   \
   l    l    r    r
  /\   /    /\    /
  l l  l    r r  r
```

Max complete subtree is

```
          m     
         ....
    /  \     /   \
   m    m    m    m
  /\   /    /\    /
  m m  m    r r  r
```

4. `r1 < r2` and `w1 == 2^r1` when node will have `(r1 + 1, 2 * w1)` Example:

```
         root     
         ....
    /  \      /   \
   l    l     r    r
  /\   / \    /\    /\
  l l  l  l   r r  r  r
             /
            r
```

Max complete subtree is

```
          m     
         ....
    /  \      /   \
   m    m     m    m
  /\   / \    /\    /\
 m  m  m  m   m m  m  m
             /
            r
```

5. `r1 < r2` and `w1 < 2^r1` when node will have `(r1 + 1, w1)`

Example:

```
         root     
         ....
    /  \      /   \
   l    l     r    r
  /\   /      /\    /\
  l l  l      r r  r  r
             /
            r
```

Max complete subtree is

```
          m     
         ....
    /  \      /   \
   m    m     m    m
  /\   /     /\    /\
 m  m  m     r r  r  r
            /
            r
```

Based on this rules you can calculate `(r, w)` for each node using a recursion. It will take `O(n)`. When you find a node with max rank `r` among this nodes find node with max `w` and this node should be a solution.

Comment: That doesn't take into account the left justified condition, for example if a node has 2 children, and both are complete, that doesn't mean that the tree rooted at node is complete as there may be a gap at the last level between the two child suibtrees

Comment: Also note that the problem is for a complete subtree and not a full subtree, and note the definition of a complete subtree in the question

Comment: If for some node we find a max full tree from this node, then max complete tree should have same height or bigger by one, if first left node in last level has children.

Comment: Consider a simple example, say I take have a tree with height 4, but the last level has only 2 nodes in the middle having the same parent, considering only full trees I would get the whole tree as a complete tree, because I am only considering ranks, but it is not

Comment: I see, I update algorithm according this requirement.

Comment: Can you explain cases 3, 4 and 5, in case 3, left and right subtrees are of same height, the last level in left subtree is not full, doesn't that mean that the subtree cannot be complete, in case 4 and 5, the right subtree has a larger height than left subtree, doesn't that automatically mean that the resultant subtree cannot be complete ?

Comment: I added examples for cases 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: If the definition of subtree was "a tree consisting of a node in T and ALL of its descendants in T", then these examples would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post while I was working on a variant of Elements of Programming Interviews. And I would like to share my idea and code.

Any comments are welcomed.

I am using recursion to solve this problem. 
max is used to store the maximum size ever occurred ( I used an array since java is by value). 
the return value info contains information about whether the tree
passed in is a complete tree or not. Only return the tree size when it is complete, otherwise return (-1, false). 
If a subtree T' is not complete, its size will never be selected to compose a larger complete tree. And the size of all T's subtrees will always recorded in max, so we will never miss any values.

Below is how it works

- Base case: root == null or root is leaf
- Recursively handle left child and right child.
- Process current tree based on return values of left/right child - leftInfo and rightInfo.
- If neither is complete, the tree is not complete, no need to update
  max.  If either is complete, the tree is not complete, update max to
  the greater size of left and right.  If both are complete, the tree
  is possible to be complete. First check if the left is perfect, and
  right satisfy the height requirement. If they are, then return (true,
  newSize). Otherwise, the tree is not complete, update max to be
  greater value of left and right.

Below is my code.It should be time O(n) and space O(h) where h is the height of the tree.(If it is balanced, otherwise the worst case will be O(n)).

```
 public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TreeNode[] trees = new TreeNode[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            trees[i].val = i;
        }
    }

    public int largestCompleteTree(TreeNode root){
        int[] max = new int[1];
        helper(root, max);
        return max[0];
    }

    private Info helper(TreeNode root, int[] max){
        //Base case:
        if(root == null){
            return new Info(0, true);
        }

        if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
            max[0] = Math.max(max[0], 1);
            return new Info(1, true);
        }

        //Recursion
        Info leftInfo = helper(root.left, max);
        Info rightInfo = helper(root.right, max);  

        //Process based on left subtree and right subtree.
        //Neither is complete.
        if(!leftInfo.isComplete && !rightInfo.isComplete){
            //Do not need to update the max value.
            return new Info(-1, false);
        }
        //One of the subtree is complete, the current tree is not complete
        else if(!leftInfo.isComplete || !rightInfo.isComplete){
            if(leftInfo.isComplete){
                max[0] = Math.max(max[0], leftInfo.size);
                return new Info(-1, false);//the value has been recorded
            }else{
                max[0] = Math.max(max[0], rightInfo.size);
                return new Info(-1, false);
            }
        }
        //Both subtrees are complete,           
        else{
            int size = 0;
            if(((rightInfo.size & (rightInfo.size + 1)) == 0 &&
                leftInfo.size >= rightInfo.size &&
                leftInfo.size <= rightInfo.size*2 + 1)||
                ((leftInfo.size & (leftInfo.size + 1)) == 0 &&
                        rightInfo.size >= (leftInfo.size - 1)/2 &&
                        rightInfo.size <= leftInfo.size))
                {
                    size = leftInfo.size + rightInfo.size + 1;
                    max[0] = Math.max(max[0], size);
                    return new Info(size, true);
                }
             else{ //find the subtree with the greater size
                size = leftInfo.size > rightInfo.size ? leftInfo.size : rightInfo.size;
                max[0] = Math.max(max[0], size);
                return new Info(0, false);
            } 
        }   
    }
    class Info {
        boolean isComplete;
        int size;

        public Info(int size, boolean isComplete){
            this.isComplete = isComplete;
            this.size = size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't work, because of the strict requirement on the left subtree to contain nodes strictly a power of 2, for example consider a simple tree where the root has 2 children, the left child has another left child, while the right child has no children, in this case, at root, we check the left child to contain 4 nodes, but it only contains 2, so we will not consider it as a complete tree, but it is

Comment: again, try to look at my definition of a complete tree, all levels are full except the last, which can contain any number of nodes

Comment: Good point. For a tree node root, its left and right could be both complete. To determine if they can form a complete tree: 1) If right tree is perfect, then leftSize need to satisfy leftSize >= rightSize && leftSize <= 2 * rightSize + 1.  2) Or if left tree is perfect, then rightSize need to satisfy rightSize <= leftSize  && rightSize >= leftSize/2 -1. If either conditions is satisfied, then we can calculate the new size and update max.

Answer (score 1):

Met this task in 'Elements of Programming Interviews' book, and it seems that I found a quite easy solution, still not sure if it's correct, but tested it on a couple of cases and it worked:

```
private struct str
        {
            public bool isComplete;
            public int height, size;
            public str(bool isComplete, int height, int size)
            {
                this.isComplete = isComplete;
                this.height = height;
                this.size = size;
            }
        }

        public int SizeOfLargestComplete()
        {
            return SizeOfLargestComplete(root).size;
        }

        private str SizeOfLargestComplete(Node n)
        {
            if (n == null)
                return new str(true, -1, 0);
            str l = SizeOfLargestComplete(n.left);
            str r = SizeOfLargestComplete(n.right);

            if (!l.isComplete || !r.isComplete)
                return new str(false, 0, Math.Max(l.size, r.size));

            int numberOfLeftTreeLeafes;
            if (l.height == -1)
                numberOfLeftTreeLeafes = 0;
            else
                numberOfLeftTreeLeafes = l.size - ((1 << l.height) - 1);

            bool leftTreeIsPerfect = (1 << (l.height + 1)) - 1 - l.size == 0;

            //if left subtree is perfect, right subtree can have leaves on last level
            if (leftTreeIsPerfect)
                if (l.size - r.size >= 0 && l.size - r.size <= numberOfLeftTreeLeafes)
                    return new str(true, l.height + 1, l.size + r.size + 1);
                else
                    return new str(false, 0, Math.Max(l.size, r.size));
            //if left subtree is not perfect, right subtree can't have leaves on last level
            //so size of right subtree must be the same as left without leaves
            else
                if (r.size == l.size - numberOfLeftTreeLeafes)
                return new str(true, l.height + 1, l.size + r.size + 1);
            else
                return new str(false, 0, Math.Max(l.size, r.size));

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggested solution: the gist is to keep track of the subtree's current number of nodes, current height and maximum height until that point.

With the current number of nodes and height, one can calculate the root's number of nodes and height via its direct childs respective information, taking into to consideration the relation between the child heights and if they are perfect subtrees or not.

Solution is O(n) time complexity and O(h) space complexity (function call stack corresponds from the root through the unique path to the current node).

Here is the Python code for this solution, and you can find the complete gist with examples [here](https://gist.github.com/lopespm/3615fc28d08f9f63125894cb8e057b0f):

```python
from collections import namedtuple


class BTN():
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

# number of nodes for a perfect tree of the given height
def max_nodes_per_height(height: int) -> int:
    return 2**(height + 1) - 1


def height_largest_complete_subtree(root: BTN) -> int:
    CompleteInformation = namedtuple('CompleteInformation', ['height', 'num_nodes', 'max_height'])

    def height_largest_complete_subtree_aux(root: BTN) -> CompleteInformation:
        if (root is None):
            return CompleteInformation(-1, 0, 0)

        left_complete_info = height_largest_complete_subtree_aux(root.left)
        right_complete_info = height_largest_complete_subtree_aux(root.right)

        left_height = left_complete_info.height
        right_height = right_complete_info.height

        if (left_height == right_height):
            if (left_complete_info.num_nodes == max_nodes_per_height(left_height)):
                new_height = left_height + 1
                new_num_nodes = left_complete_info.num_nodes + right_complete_info.num_nodes + 1
                return CompleteInformation(new_height,
                                           new_num_nodes,
                                           max(new_height, max(left_complete_info.max_height, right_complete_info.max_height))
                                          )
            else:
                new_height = left_height
                new_num_nodes = max_nodes_per_height(left_height)
                return CompleteInformation(new_height,
                                           new_num_nodes,
                                           max(new_height, max(left_complete_info.max_height, right_complete_info.max_height))
                                          )
        elif (left_height > right_height):
            if (max_nodes_per_height(right_height) == right_complete_info.num_nodes):
                new_height = right_height + 2
                new_num_nodes = min(left_complete_info.num_nodes, max_nodes_per_height(right_height + 1)) + right_complete_info.num_nodes + 1
                return CompleteInformation(new_height,
                               new_num_nodes,
                               max(new_height, max(left_complete_info.max_height, right_complete_info.max_height))
                              )
            else:
                new_height = right_height + 1
                new_num_nodes = max_nodes_per_height(right_height) + right_complete_info.num_nodes + 1
                return CompleteInformation(new_height,
                               new_num_nodes,
                               max(new_height, max(left_complete_info.max_height, right_complete_info.max_height))
                              )

        elif (left_height < right_height):
            if (left_complete_info.num_nodes == max_nodes_per_height(left_height)):
                new_height = left_height + 1
                new_num_nodes = left_complete_info.num_nodes + max_nodes_per_height(left_height) + 1
                return CompleteInformation(new_height,
                           new_num_nodes,
                           max(new_height, max(left_complete_info.max_height, right_complete_info.max_height))
                          )
            else:
                new_height = left_height
                new_num_nodes = (max_nodes_per_height(left_height - 1) * 2) + 1
                return CompleteInformation(new_height,
                           new_num_nodes,
                           max(new_height, max(left_complete_info.max_height, right_complete_info.max_height))
                          )

    return height_largest_complete_subtree_aux(root).max_height
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at a solution similar to Mikhail's above (encountered as I go though the EPI book). I've tested it against a few permutations of a complete tree, a perfect tree, a full tree and trees with sub trees that are complete .. but not exhaustively.

```
/**
 * Returns the largest complete subtree of a binary tree given by the input node
 *
 * @param root the root of the tree
 */
public int getLargestCompleteSubtree(INode<TKeyType, TValueType> root) {
    max = 0;
    calculateLargestCompleteSubtree(root);

    return max;
}

/**
 * Returns the largest complete subtree of a binary tree given by the input node
 *
 * @param root the root of the tree
 */
public TreeInfo<TKeyType, TValueType> calculateLargestCompleteSubtree(INode<TKeyType, TValueType> root) {
    int size = 0;

    // a complete subtree must have the following attributes
    // 1. All leaves must be within 1 of each other.
    // 2. All leaves must be as far left as possible, i.e, L(child).count() > R(child).count()
    // 3. A complete subtree may have only one node (L child) or two nodes (L, R).

    if (root == null)
    {
        return new TreeInfo<>(true, 0);
    }
    else if (!root.hasLeftChild() && !root.hasRightChild())
    {
        return new TreeInfo<>(true, 1);
    }

    // have children
    TreeInfo<TKeyType, TValueType> leftInfo = calculateLargestCompleteSubtree(root.getLeft());
    TreeInfo<TKeyType, TValueType> rightInfo = calculateLargestCompleteSubtree(root.getRight());

    // case 1: not a complete tree.
    if (!leftInfo.isComplete || !rightInfo.isComplete)
    {
        // Only one subtree is complete. Set it as the max and return false.
        if(leftInfo.isComplete) {
            max = Math.max(max, leftInfo.size);
        }
        else if(rightInfo.isComplete)
        {
            max = Math.max(max, rightInfo.size);
        }

        return new TreeInfo<>(false, -1);
    }

    // case 2: both subtrees complete
    int delta = Math.abs(leftInfo.size - rightInfo.size);
    if (delta <= 1)
    {
        // both are complete but R could be 1 greater...use L tree.
        size = leftInfo.size + 1;
        max = Math.max(max, size);
        return new TreeInfo<>(true, size);
    }
    else
    {
        // limit to size of R + 1 if L - R > 1, otherwise L
        if(leftInfo.size > rightInfo.size)
        {
            max = Math.max(max, leftInfo.size);
            size = rightInfo.size + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            max = Math.max(max, rightInfo.size);
            size = leftInfo.size;
        }

        return new TreeInfo<>(true, size + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive approach in python. I've tested for a few trees, worked so far.

```
# return (is_complete, max_height_so_far, is_perfect)
def is_complete_tree(node):
    # null
    if not node:
        return (True, -1, True)

    left_subtree = is_complete_tree(node.left_child)
    right_subtree = is_complete_tree(node.right_child)

    # if any of subtrees isn't complete, current tree is not complete
    if not left_subtree[0] or not right_subtree[0]:
        return (False, max(left_subtree[1], right_subtree[1]), False)

    # if both subtrees are complete, there are 2 cases in order for current tree to be complete
    # case 1: subtrees with same height
    # left subtree must be perfect
    if left_subtree[1] == right_subtree[1] and left_subtree[2]:
        return (True, left_subtree[1] + 1, right_subtree[2])

    # case 2: left subtree taller by 1
    # right subtree must be perfect
    if left_subtree[1] == right_subtree[1] + 1 and right_subtree[2]:
        return (True, left_subtree[1] + 1, False)

    # otherwise not complete
    return (False, max(left_subtree[1], right_subtree[1]), False)
```